# Extracting near-boundary points from a lattice convex polygon

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, point-in-polygon

I have been given a **lattice** convex polygon. All I want to do is iterate through all vertices and grab the interior points near it (if possible) and only in **4 directions** and of **unit distance** from the point.How do I do that?
Brief of what I did,
I iterate through all vertices. I take a vertex calculate slope between current vertex and the next and
`if` the slope is **positive** and Y-coord is **increasing** I print the `(curX-1,curY).`
`else` I print `(curX+1,curY)`
Similarly for slope being **negative**.

I leave the the cases where the slope is **INF or 0**.And also the cases where the previous slope was **INF or 0**. (optional,better methods would consider this too)

Any other better method?Is my algorithm correct? (curX=current X,curY=current Y)

Assume that the vertices are given in **CCW**.

[image: Convex Polygon,the 4 valid accessible points and the two interior valid points]

Comment: What makes this problem so complex?  The four adjacent points have nothing to do with the slope of a side.  For point (x, y), the points you need are simply (x-1, y), (x+1, y), (x, y-1), (x, y+1).  Please clarify.

Comment: @Prune Those are valid accessible points but I need both accessible and interior.

Comment: You have both -- is the problem to *differentiate* between the two sets?

Comment: @Prune Yes differentiate and take only the interior.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I determine whether a 2D Point is within a Polygon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-2d-point-is-within-a-polygon)

Comment: @Prune that uses a ray casting algo,Which costs O(n) complexity. So here for every vertex it requires O(4*n^2)?

Comment: Your posted algorithm doesn't work: it checks only against the current segment.  The point under consideration could be outside the opposite boundary of the polygon.  If the algorithm doesn't have to be accurate, I can give you an **O(zero)** algorithm :-).

Also, ray-casting is only one of the algorithms given; the winding algorithm is another cited.

Overall, if you're doing this in C++ or compatible implementation environment, check out the `polygon` package by Lucanus Simonson in the BOOST libraries.

Comment: @Prune Well does my algo work for larger polygons(more than 10 vertices)?

Comment: The failure isn't from the quantity of vertices: it's the sharpness or width of the polygon at any given vertex.